# Ember Rails URL Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have an EmberJS / Ruby on Rails application that should load different data based on site id (in my json data). mysite.com/site/1/ should load data based on the json entry with id: 1 for example.

I have my models and routes setup and my page currently loads data. The problem is that it always loads data from my first json entry "id": "1." Example: /site/2/ loads what /site/1/ should only display.

Data seen from ember console:
http://pbrd.co/ZYyfw1

Routes seen from ember console:
http://pbrd.co/ZYy4AY

The ember js:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'site', ->
    @route 'show', path: '/:site_id'

App.Router.reopen
  location: 'history'
  rootURL: '/'

attr = DS.attr

App.Site = DS.Model.extend(
  name: attr('string')
  type: attr('string')
  street: attr('string')
  city: attr('string')
  state: attr('string')
  zip: attr('string')
  phone: attr('string')
  email: attr('string')
  hours: attr('string')
  )
```

My json is coming in through the rails controller:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render json: File.open('data/sites.json').read
  end
end
```

{{name}} and {{type}} currently work great, just not dynamically. How can I setup ember to load data based on the :site_id??

I suspect I need something like this, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe its because my json is being rendered through rails and not ember?

```
App.SiteShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend(model: (params) ->
  @store.find "site", params.site_id
)
```

Comment: The images don't work

Comment: Do they work now? I updated the links.